# Derivative of $p\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_x^\infty {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}du} $?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, probability-distributions

I found a result,
I have,

$p\left( x \right) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}\int\limits_x^\infty  {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}du} $

$y =  - p\left( x \right)\log p\left( x \right) - (1 - p\left( x \right))\log (1 - p\left( x \right))$

I found a solution for the derivative of $y$ at $x=0$ is,

$\frac{{dy\left( 0 \right)}}{{dx}} = \frac{2}{\pi }$

But I could not able to show that. It comes zero for me every time.

[image: The result the paper got]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you edited the question, I edited my answer.

---

### FIRST PART

We will show that

> $$Q'(x) = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} $$

The main tool here is the [Fundamental theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus).

**First method**

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left[ \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \int_x^\infty {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}\,\mathrm du} \right] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left[\int_x^\infty {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}\,\mathrm du}\right]\\
&\overset{t=-u}{=}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{-x} {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2}}}\,\mathrm dt}\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left[\int_{-\infty}^{-x} {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{t^2}}}{2}}}\,\mathrm dt}\right]\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} {{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{x^2}}}{2}}}\\
\end{split}
$$

**Second method (essentially the same)**

Let $G(x)$ a primitive of $\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$, i. e. $G'(x) = \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$; therefore

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} \left[ \int_x^\infty {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}\,\mathrm du} \right] &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x}\left[G(+\infty)-G(x)\right] \\
&=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d x} G(-x)\\
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}}  G'(-x)  \\
&= -\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}
\end{split}
$$

**Third method**

Remembering that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\operatorname e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, \mathrm du = \sqrt{2\pi}$ we can write
$$
\int_{x}^{+\infty}\operatorname e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, \mathrm du = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\operatorname e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, \mathrm du -\int_{-\infty}^x \operatorname e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, \mathrm du = \sqrt{2\pi} - \int_{-\infty}^x \operatorname e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\, \mathrm du
$$
And then apply FTC.

---

### SECOND PART

According to your notation we have

> $$C(x) := 2 \log 2 -2h\left(Q\left(\sqrt x\right)\right) $$

If we evaluate $\dot C$, thanks to the chain rule we have

$$
\begin{split}
\dot C (x) &= -2h'\left(Q\left(\sqrt x\right)\right) \cdot Q'\left(\sqrt x\right) \cdot \frac{1}{2 \sqrt x} \\
&= -\log \left[ \frac{Q\left(\sqrt x\right)}{1-Q\left(\sqrt x\right)} \right]\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \operatorname{e}^{-\frac{x}{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt x}\\
&= \frac{\operatorname{e}^{-\frac{x}{2}}}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi}} \cdot \frac{\log \left( 1 - Q\left(\sqrt x\right)\right) -\log Q\left(\sqrt x\right) }{\sqrt x}
\end{split}
$$

Since $Q(0)=\frac{1}{2}$, we obtain an indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$. Can you handle from here?

---

### THIRD PART

We have to evaluate

> $$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\log \left( 1 - Q\left(\sqrt x\right)\right) -\log Q\left(\sqrt x\right) }{\sqrt x} \overset{y=\sqrt x}{=} \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\log \left( 1 - Q(y) \right) -\log Q(y) }{y}$$

to be continued...

Comment: Thank you. I understand the integration now, but the problem is $p\left( 0 \right) = 0.5$ $\begin{array}{l}
\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} =  - p'\left( x \right)\left( {1 + \log p\left( x \right)} \right) - \left\{ { - p'\left( x \right)\left( {1 + \log (1 - p\left( x \right))} \right)} \right\}\\
 =  - p'\left( x \right)\left( {\log \left( {\frac{{p\left( x \right)}}{{1 - p\left( x \right)}}} \right)} \right)
\end{array}$. Therefore it makes the result zero. But $\frac{{dy\left( 0 \right)}}{{dx}} = \frac{2}{\pi }$ is a legit result. But I find it zero that i explained in this comment. Again thank you.

Comment: Can i prove $\frac{{dy\left( 0 \right)}}{{dx}} = \frac{2}{\pi }$? I think my $\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}$ expression  is correct.

Comment: I edited my answer, however it looks like $y'(0)\neq \frac{2}{\pi}$.

Comment: Thank you. I added the image of a reference paper where the author found this. And he told to take $a = \sqrt {SNR} $. and put $a=0$ at the end. That very cumbersome looking. Thank you.

Comment: I just saw that. Thank you a lot. Can I ask that why matlab gives result $Q(0)=0.5$? Where as it is $sqrt(\frac{\pi }{2})$. Again thank you a lot.

Comment: You are right, thank you I will fix it.

Comment: But your last results were in coherent with the result given in the paper. That I edited in the question.

Comment: But your paper is interested in evaluating the derivative of $h(Q(\sqrt x))$, right?

Comment: My last question is how you got, $\int\limits_{ - \infty }^\infty  {{{\mathop{\rm e}\nolimits} ^{ - \frac{{{u^2}}}{2}}}du}  = \sqrt {2\pi } $? Again thank you for your suggestion and showing the proof.

Comment: We [know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) that $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \operatorname e^{- u} \, \mathrm d u  = \sqrt{\pi}$$ We can reduce to this case by substituing $ t = \frac{u}{\sqrt 2}$

Comment: Yes. But as $Q(\sqrt x )$ derivative w.r.t. $x$ is undefined so he took  $\sqrt x=a$ and found the derivative with respect to a and evaluated at $a=0$

Comment: And is it same for $u^2 $ instead of $u$. Like substituting $t=\sqrt {\frac{u}{2}} $.

Comment: Be careful!
$$\frac{\mathrm d }{\mathrm d x}h(Q(\sqrt x))= h'( Q\left(\sqrt x \right))\cdot \frac{Q'(\sqrt x)}{2\sqrt x}$$

Hence when you evaluate $\dot C (0)$ you will find a indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109475/discussion-between-sewer-keeper-and-hasan).

Comment: Sure. I am there. Thank you